# How to flatten 3d astronomical coordinates into 2d polar form in Python

Tags: python, simulation, coordinate-transformation, astropy, astronomy

I am making a 2d simulation of the solar system. For that you need a starting point for all planets. Right now I am storing that data in this form (ignore the `color`, `radius`, `mass` and `Max_Trail_Length` columns as they are cosmetics for the model):

| Name | Color (RGB) | Radius (km) | Mass (kg) | Distance (AU) | Velocity (m/s) | Direction (radians) | Max_Trail_Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sun | (255, 255, 0) | 6963400 | 1.98847e+30 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 |
| Mercury | (255, 0, 0) | 2440 | 3.3011e+23 | 0.393 | 47362 | pi / 2 | 200 |
| Venus | (255, 165, 0) | 6052 | 4.8675e+24 | 0.723 | 35021.4 | pi / 2 | 600 |
| Earth | (0, 0, 255) | 6371 | 5.9722e+24 | 1 | 29784.8 | pi / 2 | 800 |
| Mars | (255, 0, 0) | 3390 | 6.4171e+23 | 1.52 | 24130.8 | pi / 2 | 2000 |
| Jupiter | (255, 222, 173) | 69911 | 1.8982e+27 | 5.203 | 13070 | pi / 2 | 10000 |
| Saturn | (210, 180, 140) | 58232 | 5.6834e+26 | 9.737 | 9690 | pi / 2 | 20000 |
| Uranus | (0, 0, 128) | 25362 | 8.681e+25 | 19.61 | 6810 | pi / 2 | 50000 |
| Neptune | (0, 0, 255) | 24622 | 1.02413e+26 | 29.897 | 5430 | pi / 2 | 200000 |

As you can see, the direction is the same, so all planets are aligned, and the distance and velocity data is just the average.

For the record, I do not plan to make this into a 3d model, even though it would mitigate this problem entirely.

I want to collect real data from a date (January 1. 1750) using `astropy`, however when i collect the position and velocity using `pos, vel = coordinates.get_body_barycentric_posvel(name, time)` (`coordinates` from `astropy`), I get 3d data, as you can expect. But I want to convert it into data similar as I at the moment have.

I can't seem to do it right, as flattening the z axis doesn't work (I though it might be ignored at first as the solar system is relatively flat).

Here is the code I have right now for collecting this data.

```py
import csv
import os

import numpy as np
from astropy import coordinates as coord
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.time import Time


# FIXME: Temporary wrong solution
def transform_data(pos, vel):
    pos = coord.CartesianRepresentation(pos.x, pos.y, 0 * u.au)
    vel = coord.CartesianDifferential(vel.x, vel.y, 0 * u.au / u.s)
    vel = vel.norm().to(u.m / u.s).value
    dist = pos.norm().to(u.AU).value

    return dist, vel


def get_path():
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    data_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'data')
    os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
    file_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'solsystem_data_1750.csv')
    return file_path


def process_data(time, writer):
    for name in ['Sun', 'Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']:
        pos, vel = coord.get_body_barycentric_posvel(name, time)

        dist, vel = transform_data(pos, vel)

        angle = np.arctan2(pos.y, pos.x).value

        writer.writerow([name, f'{dist:.5f}', f'{vel:.5f}', f'{angle:.5f}'])


def main():
    coord.solar_system_ephemeris.set('jpl')

    time = Time('1970-01-01')  # TODO: Change to 1750-01-01, but 1750 is a dubious year

    file_path = get_path()

    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Name', 'Distance (AU)', 'Velocity (m/s)', 'Direction (radians)'])

        process_data(time, writer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to know if I can either modify my `transform_data` function, or collect the data in some sort of other way.

I couldn't find any 2d data from `astropy`, and I haven't found a way to convert the coordinates in a good way yet. I researched some alternatives to `astropy`, like just collecting the data from [NASA's Horizons System](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/), however I there run into the same problem of flattening the data.

Comment: Since this is a conceptual question about how to properly represent 3D astronomical data in a 2D format, it seems like a site dedicated to answering general questions about astronomy (like [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)) would be more likely to have an answer for this, in case this post doesn't get enough traction here. It's not really a programming question, since you don't know how to do it _not_ in code.

Comment: Yes that is true. I don't really have any experience in astronomy and such so I don't know any good forums for answering this. Any recommendations for a site I can post to would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have a link in my comment actually, it is to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh shoot I overlooked that hahah. Thank you